# My cloud-based server runs a SQL Server Query 50% slower after an upgrade to dual core from single core

Tags: sql-server, tomcat, cloud

My application runs SQL Server 2008 on Windows Server 2008 using Tomcat.

I am using a Cloud-based server

One of my queries takes exactly 48 seconds to run from the application. It pulls 425 records from the database.

I was not surprised by the length of time.

Although a similar query on Oracle ran in 6 seconds, the Oracle setup had 2GB of memory and a quad-processor, whereas my SQL Server set up was 1GB of memory and a single 2.66GHZ processor.

Therefore I increased my server spec to 2GB. There was no change.

I then increased my server spec to dual processor from single processor.
I was surprised to find that the query now took longer - exactly 70 seconds!

I am aware that the conversion of the query from P/SQL to T/SQL may have been done in a very non-efficient way. And there may be speed differences between Oracle and SQL Server. 
However my main question is really, why should the same query now run slower on a dual-core system than on a single-core?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the hypervisor used and the total load on the server, dual virtual CPUs can result in getting (significantly) less CPU time, as some hypervisor's scheduler insists of finding 2 CPUs that are schedulable at the same time. If your query is single-threaded, the advantage of a second CPU is zero, but getting less CPU time makes it slower.

Exactly the opposite direction is another possibility: If your query is multithreaded and your storage is slow, then the 2 threads can create a random IO storm, that decreases your storage throughput.

Comment: A friend of mine suggested to me to change the SQL server properties after changing the hardware. From management studio right click on the server name and choose properties. I haven't tried this yet.