# Disparity between SqlReader execution times on same .NET project but different computers

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, ado.net

I'm working on a team project that reads data from a MSSQL server.  We are using an asynchronous call to fetch the data.

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString);
SqlCommand cmdData = new SqlCommand("get_report", conn);
cmdData.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

conn.Open();
IAsyncResult asyResult = cmdData.BeginExecuteReader();

try
{
    SqlDataReader drResult = cmdData.EndExecuteReader(asyResult);
    table.Load(drResult);
}
catch (SqlException ex)
{
    throw;
}
```

The project itself uses TFS source control with gated check-ins, and we have verified that both computers are running the exact same version of the project.  We are also using the same user login and executing the stored procedure with the exact same parameters (which are not listed for brevity).

The stored procedure itself takes 1:54 to return 42000 rows under SQL Server Management Studio.  While running on Windows 7 x86, the .NET code takes roughly the same amount of time to execute as on SSMS, and the code snippet above executes perfectly.  However, on my computer running Windows 7 x64, the code above encounters an error at the `EndExecuteReader` line at the 0:40 mark.  The error returned is "Invalid Operation.  The connection has been closed."

Adding `cmdData.CommandTimeout = 600` allows the execution to proceed, but the data takes over 4 minutes to be returned, and we are at a loss as to explain what might be going on.

Some things we considered: my computer has .NET 4.5 Framework installed, is running 64-bit OS against 32-bit assemblies, may be storing information in the local project file that isn't being synchronized to the TFS server.  But we can't seem to figure out exactly what might actually be causing the disparity in times.

**Anyone have any ideas as to why this disparity exists or can give me suggestions of where to look to isolate the problem?**

Comment: can you provide the exact error message you are getting?

Comment: @pdriegen Yeah, I realized I'd forgotten to add that after re-reading.  It's in there now, I'm getting "Invalid Operation.  The connection has been closed."

Comment: Do you have Sql Server and application on same first machine and accessing the DB remotely from second machine.

Comment: @Romil both are accessing a remote SQL server

Comment: I had something vaguely [similar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8926005/my-cloud-based-server-runs-a-sql-server-query-50-slower-after-an-upgrade-to-dua)... Did you go into SSMS, right-click on server-name, select Properties, and then under "processors" click the appropriate boxes?

Answer (score 0):

Invalid Operation error is received when EndExecuteReader was called more than once for a single command execution, or the method was mismatched against its execution method.

Comment: But how is it that, on the exact same project, one computer runs the code fine, the other doesn't but can be fixed by changing the CommandTimeout?

Comment: Given the same code is running successfully in one environment but not another, a coding error seems unlikely.